# Is the facial hair of Tolkien's dwarves unshaveable?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, dwarves

By which I mean that they could not be shaven, due to some sort of magic on them. Or are they simply omnipresent, but not magically protected?

Comment: IS there any reason to believe it would be unshaveable?

Comment: Because all dwarves have them...it seems to be part of their nature, almost.

Comment: All Men have hair yet it's not uncuttable... flawed logic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [*The History of Middle Earth Vol. 11*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_Middle-earth)

> The Naugrim were ever, as they still remain, short and squat in
> stature; they were deep-breasted, strong in the arm, and stout in the
> leg, and their beards were long. Indeed this strangeness they have
> that no Man nor Elf has ever seen a beardless Dwarf - **unless he were
> shaven in mockery,** and would then be more like to die of shame than of
> many other hurts that to us would seem more deadly.

It's not clear *how* this fact is known, but that a dwarf can be shaved (if under duress) is evident.

---

Their beards can also be burned by dragonfire.

> "The few of us [dwarves] that were well outside sat and wept in hiding, and
> cursed Smaug; and there we were unexpectedly **joined by my father and
> my grandfather with singed beards**. They looked very grim but they said
> very little.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Hobbit, or There and Back Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit)</sup></sub>

Comment: Well, maybe they still would have had part of their beard, like the mustache, goatee, or sideburns. But I see that this answer is probably quite correct, so I thank you for it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say *shaving* particularly, in the sense of removing all traces, but at least at the time of Bilbo's adventure Dwarven facial hair was cuttable.

From *The Hobbit*, chapter 8, "Flies and Spiders":

> Somehow or other Fili was got on to the branch, and then he did his
> best to help the hobbit, although he was feeling very sick and ill
> from spider-poison, and from hanging most of the night and the next
> day wound round and round with only his nose to breathe through. It
> took him ages to get the beastly stuff out of his eyes and eyebrows,
> and **as for his beard, he had to cut most of it off**.